# Restore the body field

Tags: 8, nodes

I am new to Drupal 8. I had a understanding that, Drupal by default provides you a Title and Body field for content type.

I have an ongoing project, and I realized that one of the content types is missing the body field. How can I restore it?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it through the UI:

1. Visit /admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT-TYPE/fields/add-field.
2. Choose the body field from the *Re-use an existing field* select.
3. Click *Save and Continue*.
4. Configure the field for that specific content type and save.

Comment: Body cannot be restored this way, unfortunately